# Как код сделать асинхронным?

Tags: python, selenium, asyncio, chromedriver

Как этот код можно выполнить асинхронно, он работает, но синхронно. Ведь я сравнивал по времени выполнения и разницы никакой нет

```
import asyncio
from selenium import webdriver
import time

def leagues_selection():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get("https://www.flashscore.com")
    accept = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#onetrust-accept-btn-handler").click()
    time.sleep(1)
    i = 0
    for country_block in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".lmc__block"):
        count = len(block)
        if block.is_displayed():
            block.click()
            i +=1
            print(f"Количество итераций: {i}/{count}")
    driver.close()

async def scraper():
    leagues_selection()

start_time = time.time()
def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(scraper())
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
print(f"Время выполнения кода: {time.time() - start_time} сек.")
```

Comment: https://github.com/HDE/arsenic

Comment: Только вот на время выполнения асинхронность не повлияет вообще никак. Скорее всего даже слегка замедлится

Comment: Что бы что то выполнялось асинхронно, надо сначала решить какие вообще операции могли бы выполняться параллельно и обложить это все async/await. Конечно при этом где то должна быть функция, которая в принципе способна выполнятся асинхронно. Если я правильно понимаю тут написанное, то вы сначала получаете по сети какую то страницу, а потом ее разбираете. Весь разбор идет уже у вас в памяти на вашем процессоре. Асинхронность может дать выигрыш только если вы отправите запрос в сеть на получение страницы и вместо того что бы ждать, займетесь другой работой.

Comment: Я не вижу что бы в вашем коде можно было бы сделать параллельно с получением страницы. Если например click() вызывает какие то действия по сети, то может быть и можно было бы сделать несколько одновременно, но тогда это должен явно поддерживать webdriver, для этого у него наверняка должен быть отдельный набор асинхронных функций, вместо тех что используете вы. у него есть поддержка асинхронности ? Вы посмотрели как именно ее вызывать ?

Comment: В том то и дело что selenium не поддерживает асинхронность

Comment: Тогда вы ничего не сделаете. Цепочка вызовов async/await должна пройти сквозь все функции вплоть до низкоуровневых, обращающихся к сети. А для этого все эти функции должны быть написаны специальным образом. Включая все функции внутри selenium